# Can I use enum as a ConverterParameter?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

Currently i'm using integer as the `ConverterParameter`, and casting it to the `Enum` in the `Converter`. I find it very unreadable in the `XAML`.

I wonder if there is a way to declare the `Enum` in the resources section and pass its value as `ConverterParameter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `x:Static`.

```
{Binding ..., ConverterParameter={x:Static YourEnum.YourEnumValue}}
```

Comment: I get "Type MyEnum was not found" :( What am I missing?

Comment: I've inserted the namespace "local:", and it fixed it. Thanks a lot!